# How can I set a class to the parent element if the child contains certain class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

So I have this:

```css
body {
   padding-left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div>child</div>
</body>
```

Sometimes this child contains a variation:

```html
<body>
   <div class="service-error">child</div>
</body>
```

So I want to do something like this:

```css
.service-error {
  body & {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

But it is not working, any ideas on what is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to target a parent element using css since they follow the cascading rule which is "top to bottom". I would suggest using javascript to select the parent and add a class.

Comment: I am using scss/sass, is impossible with it too?

Comment: Yes, not possible with scss/sass as well. It  is simply a superset of css offering simpler and efficient ways to write css. Hope that answers your question. 

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot set styles for the parent tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), but since you have a specific class name, you can set when to enable `padding-left` style or not.

In this example, by default all of the `div`s inside the `container` element should have `padding-left` style with `350px`. But when you add the class name `service-error` to specify it, it would be reset.

```css
.container div {
  padding-left: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.service-error {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>child</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="service-error">child</div>
</div>
```